# Deploy a new contract

Tags: contract-deployment

I know that my question is probably funny, but I need to understand the deployment workflow more deeply.

As many people use OpenZeppelin, I am not an exception. I imported the file into my contract and in Remix I see a few contracts to deploy(see image). Locally, I always deploy only my contract, and it works perfectly, but what about live development? As far as I understood, I will deploy all OpenZeppelin contracts along with my, which cost an additional gas. Is that correct? What is the best/rational way to deploy contracts using external ones?
[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contracts use inheritance. So it goes something like A > B > C, where C inherits B and B inherits A.

Assuming the A, B and C are non-abstract contracts, you can deploy any one of them. If you deploy A, the resulting contract has A's functionality. If you deploy B, it has functionalities from A and B. And C has functionalities from A, B and C.

With inheritance, the contracts are flattened before deployment. So if you deploy B, A's functionality is included/flattened into the same contract, and therefore you only deploy one contract.

Comment: I am asking as I sometimes saw that people deployed 10 different contracts where only 1 was their own and rest of them were OpenZeppelin`s. I mean, you check any NFT contract in etherscan and inside "Contract" tab you can see 10 separate files instead of 1.

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple files which are used for compiling, but in bytecode there's just one contract.